# How do I convert a JSON file with object field in YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS format into a list of lists?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time-series

I have a .json file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "date_time": "2020-01-01 07:00:00",
    "second_field": 2,
    "third_field": 3,
  }, …
]
```

I'm importing it like this:

```
import myJson from '../data/mystuff.json';
const data = myJson;
```

And I would like to change it, inside my .js file, to

```
data: [
    [1400425947000, second_field, third_field],
    [1400425948000, second_field, third_field],
    [1400425949000, second_field, third_field],
    [1400425950000, second_field, third_field],
    ...
]
```

So that it can be used to construct a [TimeSeries object from the react-timeseries-charts library](https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts#data-format). How can I

1. programmatically change each YY-MM-DD value of the JSON objects into JS date notation, inside my .js file?
2. convert the JSON objects into a list of lists?

Comment: Your JSON Syntax is not correct, use double quotes `"` instead of these `“`. Also your `data` example is an array of arrays not a list of lists

Comment: @Luca Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var arr = [{"date_time":"2020-01-01 07:00:00","second_field":2,"third_field":3},{"date_time":"2019-01-01 07:00:00","second_field":1,"third_field":3}];

var result = arr.map(({date_time,second_field,third_field})=>[new Date(date_time).getTime(),second_field,third_field]);

console.log(result);
```

You can even try the following, it will work for any numbers of fields:

```js
var arr = [{"date_time":"2020-01-01 07:00:00","second_field":2,"third_field":3},{"date_time":"2019-01-01 07:00:00","second_field":1,"third_field":3}];

var result = arr.map(({date_time,...prop})=>[new Date(date_time).getTime()].concat(Object.values(prop)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I would like to mark this as the answer, but I'm not sure it's a list of lists. It looks like it from the console output, but when I try to construct a TimeSeries for this, I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isChronological' of null" error. Is it definitely a list of lists?

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe yes it is a list of list :-)

Comment: Thank you! I accepted it. Could you help me interpret the error? [Here](https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts#data-format) is the documentation. Did I misinterpret it? Is it not asking for a list of lists?

Comment: @JohnDoeVsJoeSchmoe yes as per documentation, list of list for points, but data is an object which contains certain other properties also.